# missingpluginexception(no implementation found for method distanceBetween on channel flutter/baseflow.com/geolocator.methods

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocalização

Ao tentar calcular um frete usando a distancia do CEP cadastrado ao do usuário, me deparo com esse erro:

> missingpluginexception(no implementation found for method
> distanceBetween on channel flutter/baseflow.com/geolocator.methods

```
    Future<void> setAddress(Address address) async {
    loading = true;

    this.address = address;

    if (await calculateDelivery(address.lat, address.long)) {
      user.setAddress(address);
      loading = false;
    } else {
      loading = false;
      return Future.error('Endereço fora do raio de entrega :(');
    }
  }

  void removeAddress() {
    address = null;
    deliveryPrice = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> calculateDelivery(double lat, double long) async {
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await firestore.document('aux/delivery').get();

    final latStore = doc.data['lat'] as double;
    final longStore = doc.data['long'] as double;

    final base = doc.data['base'] as num;
    final km = doc.data['km'] as num;
    final maxkm = doc.data['maxkm'] as num;

    double dis =
        await Geolocator().distanceBetween(latStore, longStore, lat, long);

    dis /= 1000.0;

    debugPrint('Distance $dis');

    if (dis > maxkm) {
      return false;
    }

    deliveryPrice = base + dis * km;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Esse é o botão que chama o codigo a cima

```
   if (cartManager.loading)
        LinearProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        disabledColor: Colors.red.withAlpha(100),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: !cartManager.loading
            ? () async {
                if (Form.of(context).validate()) {
                  Form.of(context).save();
                  try {
                    await context.read<CartManager>().setAddress(address);
                  } catch (e) {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text('$e'),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ));
                  }
                }
              }
            : null,
        child: const Text('Calcular Frete'),
      ),
    ],
  );
else if (address.zipCode != null)
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
    child:
        Text('${address.street}, ${address.number}\n${address.district}\n'
            '${address.city} - ${address.state}'),`
```

Meu Pubspec.yaml

```
  name: Flutter2
    description: A new Flutter project.
    
    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
         
    
          
        
       
    
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
      cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
      firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
      firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
      provider: ^4.1.3
      carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
      flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
      transparent_image: ^1.0.0
      alphabet_list_scroll_view: ^1.0.6
      faker: ^1.2.1
      image_picker: ^0.6.7+1
      image_cropper: ^1.2.2
      uuid: ^2.0.4
      dio: ^3.0.9
      brasil_fields: ^0.2.0
      geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
      sliding_up_panel: ^1.0.2
      screenshot: ^0.1.1
      gallery_saver: ^2.0.1
      flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
      flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
      url_launcher: ^5.4.11
      map_launcher: ^0.5.0
      flip_card: ^0.4.4
      mask_text_input_formatter: ^1.0.7
      credit_card_type_detector: ^1.1.0
      keyboard_actions: ^3.2.1+1
      cloud_functions: ^0.5.0
      cpf_cnpj_validator: ^1.0.5
      firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
      flushbar: ^1.10.4
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
    
    
        
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
      assets:
        - assets/
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
    
      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      # assets:
      #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
      #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
    
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
    
      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
    
      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Nos mostre como está teu pubspec.yaml, [EDITE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/463757/edit) a sua pergunta e coloque ele nela, por favor. Deve haver algum conflito, pois testei aqui da mesma forma que você e o plugin funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Link útil (Ou nem tanto) sobre o problema: [MissingPluginException when trying to use](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/311)

Answer (score 1):

Essa mensagem de erro indica que não foi achado o método requisitado por você.
Como esse método [existe](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) e está corretamente utilizado, você deve verificar alguns pontos:

- Você precisa rodar o comando de obtenção de pacotes `flutter pub get` (A maioria das IDE's já contém um botão de atalho para isso).
- Você precisa **fechar** o app e **rodar** de novo (Apertar o "play" em sua IDE ou rodar o `flutter run` novamente). Se você está usando Hot Restart ou Hot Reload, isso não irá funcionar pois o Flutter precisa injetar essas dependências em partes específicas de cada plataforma. Hot Restart e Hot Reload não são o suficiente para disparar esse tipo de injeção.
- Por último, rodar um `flutter clean` antes do passo acima ajuda, mas acredito não ser necessário.

Para maiores informações consulte esta [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912) (em inglês sobre um problema relacionado que contém essas informações).

Comment: +1. Apenas informe que o link da _issue_ não é referente ao problema da pergunta, mas que é algo relacionado e pode auxiliar. Apenas para não confundir a galera.

Comment: Eu reinicei  o App, sai da execução, dei o flutter clean, flutter pack get, flutter pub get, depois abri o emulador e dei flutter run novamente, problema persiste, continua mostrando o mesmo erro, tambem reinicei o PC e fiz o processo todo novamente para garantir, mas o erro persiste

Comment: @Matheus Resposta editada. @giovanni, além disso, poderia por favor informar o valor de ```compileSdkVersion __```, dentro do arquivo ```android/app/build.gradle```? Esse valor precisa ser no mínimo 28. É um dos passos iniciais descritos na página do pacote utilizado.

Comment: essa e a versão  android {
    compileSdkVersion 28